# how to update listview from a linqdatasource using the event ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, sql, linq, listview

I have a linqdatasource witch perform a ListView1 list.  The listview change when the user select a doctor name from a Dropdownlist.   I attached a OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" event to it.
The column of the listview1 are apointmentId, doctorName, dateApointment, clientName and a checkbox.

I want to update the row which got selected by the checkbox (basically the user selected a date for his apointment).

```
 <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="ApointmentDataContext" 
  EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" 
  TableName="Apointment" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True">
            <WhereParameters>
               <asp:ControlParameter 
                   Name="doctorName" 
                   ControlID="DropDownList1" 
                   PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                   Type="String" />
             </WhereParameters>

 </asp:LinqDataSource>

 <div class="center">
    <asp:Label ID="lblDoctorName" runat="server" Text="Choose a doctor name"> </asp:Label>
    <div class="value-right"> 
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="180px" AutoPostBack="true" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Doctor A" Value="Doctor A" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Doctor B" Value="Doctor B" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Doctor C" Value="Doctor C" />
       </asp:DropDownList> 
    </div>  
 </div>   <br/><br/>

 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="apointmentId" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem"    
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
      <tr style="">
         <td>
            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
         </td>
         <!--<td>
                <asp:Label ID="ApointmentIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                   Eval("ApointmentId") %>' />
             </td>   -->
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="doctorName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("doctorName") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateApointment", "{0:dd-MM-
              yyyy}") %>' />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="ClientLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("clientName") %>' />
         </td>
         <input id="MyCheckBox" value='<%# Eval("apointmentId") %>'
                             type="checkbox" runat="server" />
```

The following code will list all the available dates from the selected doctors.  The goal is the user will select an available date (by checking the checkbox).  Now I want to be able to update this row in the apointement table.   I am missing the code to be able to use the ListView1 properties.

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ApointmentDataContext db = new ApointmentDataContext())
    {
       Listview1.
    }       
}
```

When I put ListView1 here I got the error message The name ListView1 does not exist in the current context.

I will like to be able to retrieve the guid or the ApointmentId to be able to update the selected row.

I got the checkbox selection by doing this.  Maybe we can do something here ?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iCptCheckBox = 0;
    int indxChkBox = 0;

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {

        var chk = item.FindControl("MyCheckBox") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox;
        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
            indxChkBox = Convert.ToInt32(chk.Value);
            iCptCheckBox++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your help to guide me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two issues here:

1. That your listview is not visible in your code behind, to solve this please clean up your page designer.cs file and make a small change ( could add a space) in aspx, and regenerate the designer file. This should solve this issue.
2. Second issue getting the selected item, you should use SelectedDataKey property of listview to get the selected id. I can see that you have appointmentid as the datakey name.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did item 1 (make a change to the designer file.  I can now get rid of the ListView1 error.  As per as item 2 I put ListView1.SelectedDataKey but the only option I have here is Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString, Value, Values.   I cannot find the SelectedItem option.   Can you provide me a small example please will be very appreciate. Thanks